# How small can you make the DataType in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, types, integer

I know that we can change the number of bits in the datatype of the int or the float, to shrink the size of the array.
Ex. You can change it from

```
dtype='int34' --> dtype='int16'
```

How small can you make this data?  int8/float8? Does this minimum sizeof 8 bits apply to every array, no matter its dimensions?

Comment: The dimensions are not really relevant. But yeah, I think a byte is the smallest itemsize

Comment: And I doubt there is `int34`, do you maybe mean `int32`?

Comment: 16, 2 bytes is smallest for floats.  8, 1 byte is ok for int, (and `uint`), but the numeric range is quite limited.  `np.uint8` is commonly used with images.  But for serious math you shouldn't be focusing on minimal size.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html): It appears that the smallest platform-independent types are indeed 8 bits. The datatype is independent of the size of the array.

Comment: Example: `np.uint8`